# How can retrieve sql query which stored in table and make dynamic php page for all queries in table

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, dynamic

I'm trying to retrieve dynamic query PHP pages. First page passing values of city or id  next page by post method.

Table looks like this:

**TABLE1**

```
-----------------------------------------------------
1     select * from tablename1 where ID = $id
2     select * from tablename1 where city = $city
-----------------------------------------------------
```

Now I run page contain code:

```
    $id = $_POST["id"];
    $city= $_POST["city"];
    $tabledata = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table1 ");
    $a=mysql_fetch_row($tabledata );

    $query_table=$a['1']; // retrieve sql query from table1 which stored in 2nd column
    echo " $query_table"; // display query
    $result = mysql_query($query_table);

    while ($field = mysql_fetch_row( $result) )
    {
        echo "<td> $field[1] </td>";
    }
```

Now, the problem is that I can't get results. `$result` is empty?

How pass `$city` or `$id` value to query?

But if I remove `WHERE`condition from **TABKE1** then it works well. So, how can I make for `WHERE` condition to pass parameters?

how can i do this . any other option here to call stored query on 1 table and process it on other page and oher table

Answer (score 0):

Use the `WHERE` and `OR` clauses in your first statement, then you can iterate each of the results returned as rows and can avoid the convoluted method above..

```
$tabledata = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE ID = {$id} OR city = {$city}");
```

Comment: but $tabledata retieve sqlquery from table1 ( column 2 ).   $query_table=$a['1'] which sotres sql query and $result = mysql_query($query_table); which is not worked .

Comment: @Mr.J There are three things incredibly important to note here. #1 - Never trust the data that your users post. Someone could easily manipulate this and delete your entire database, or worse, steal sensitive data. #2 - `mysql_` is deprecated in favor of `mysqli_`. #3 - You cannot take advantage of prepared statements in `mysqli_` using this method and therefore you're essentially defenseless. Rethink this.

Comment: Love the smell of SQL injection in the morning